# Xcode:(user defined runtime attribute)Range with minus value. Alternative?

Tags: xcode, nsrange, nsuinteger

I made a custom UITextField with an additional user defined runtime attribute validRange, which I can set in the storyboard view.
I use this property to check in the EndEditing method to validate the new set text.
I works all fine, till I had to set a valid range from {-100,100}
As NSRange uses NSUInteger, there are no minus values possible.

What is the best way to still make this happen?
Would it be acceptable if I use CGSize instead of NSRange?

**Updated Content**
Xcode only gives me the following choice of data types for the user defined runtime attributes:

[image]

This means I cannot define a new struct to create a CustomRange with NSInteger.
As Point,Size are both {NSInteger,NSInteger} data types, I thought about using them. But this would be certainly a misuse, so I am wondering if someone knows a better solution, as misusing Point or Size to get this to work.

As another workaround I could user String, which I manually would split up in a method of the custom UITextField, but then there is no type safety.

Comment: There're no correlation between NSRange or CGSize, both serve different purposes. I am wondering, what do you intend to achieve here?

Comment: Define your own `struct` using `NSInteger`. You can make it `start` and `length` or `start` and `end` depending on your needs.

Comment: @ldindu I added some information to my question, to better understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @rmaddy This is a neat idea, but I think it's not practical in this case, as I need to choose from a give list(see updated question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I would suggest you to define two NSNumber properties with suitable names to represent NSRange value instead of abusing CGSize as using CGSize confuses other readers/programmers as we there is a saying, we code for others not for ourselves.

And there is a NSNumber class method as follows

```
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)value
```

which allow you to wrap signed integer value as you intend.

Comment: I guess this is the best way to do it. I would have loved it to make this with one user defined runtime attribut, but this doesn't seem to be possible. Thanks